# How do you fix the error in resolving packages when creating a react application

Tags: reactjs, npm, npm-install

I have been trying to install a react app on my local pc but I keep getting the connectivity error although I am connected to the internet and the speed of the wifi is good.

```
Installing template dependencies using yarnpkg...
yarn add v1.22.10
[1/4] Resolving packages...
info There appears to be trouble with your network connection. Retrying...
info There appears to be trouble with your network connection. Retrying...
info There appears to be trouble with your network connection. Retrying...
info There appears to be trouble with your network connection. Retrying...
error An unexpected error occurred: "https://registry.yarnpkg.com/react: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND registry.yarnpkg.com".
info If you think this is a bug, please open a bug report with the information provided in "C:\\Users\\stanley\\Desktop\\my-app\\yarn-error.log".
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/add for documentation about this command.
`yarnpkg add @testing-library/jest-dom@^5.11.4 @testing-library/react@^11.1.0 @testing-library/user-event@^12.1.10 web-vitals@^1.0.1` failed
```

Answer (score 2):

Personally, what I did was to copy the command that the error message said to look up in the documentation, pasted it in my command line, and entered it:

```
yarnpkg add @testing-library/jest-dom@^5.11.4 @testing-library/react@^11.1.0 @testing-library/user-event@^12.1.10 web-vitals@^1.0.1
```

It worked...

Though I got some warnings, my dependencies and the create-react-app download were completed.

Comment: Hi, that is not a solution is a workaround that works for you. 
Consider to uninstall yarn and installed again globally, and also try with npm just to see if you receive the same connectivity issue

Comment: I did have a connectivity issue. I just worked with error message I got, you're probably right.

Comment: The link that was given in the error didn't provide any solution to the problem:
https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/add